# How to do daily database backup for PostgreSQL using Laravel?

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I have seen this tutorial online https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-automatic-daily-database-backup-tutorialexample.html on how to backup database daily for mysql. How to do this in postgreSQL?

**MySQL**

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class DatabaseBackUp extends Command
{
/**
 * The name and signature of the console command.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $signature = 'database:backup';

/**
 * The console command description.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $description = 'Command description';

/**
 * Create a new command instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

/**
 * Execute the console command.
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function handle()
{
    $filename = "backup-" . Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d') . ".gz";

    $command = "mysqldump --user=" . env('DB_USERNAME') ." --password=" . env('DB_PASSWORD') . " --host=" . env('DB_HOST') . " " . env('DB_DATABASE') . "  | gzip > " . storage_path() . "/app/backup/" . $filename;

    $returnVar = NULL;
    $output  = NULL;

    exec($command, $output, $returnVar);
}
```

}

Comment: Make it easy on yourself. https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup is the gold standard for this.

Comment: I believe `pg_dump` is the counterpart to mysql's `mysqldump`. Thats as much as I can tell you. It could be that it's also in the package mentioned by @ceejayoz, I havent checked

Answer (score 1):

This [backup package](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-backup/v7/introduction) is your friend ;)